# Border and border-radius CSS styles clashing on table

Tags: css

I have a table with the following style attached:

```
    .myTable{
        width:97%;
        max-height: 190px;
        padding:10px;
        margin: 10px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #D3D7DC;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
```

I want my table to have rounded edges, at the moment, the table does have the rounded edges, but the 1px border

```
border: 1px solid #D3D7DC;
```

is still square around the table, so it sort of looks like it's a table within a table...

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this may be?

Comment: you should use <div> instead of <table>

Comment: well I need to use a table for this particular project

Comment: so, don't use class .myTable, use table only

Comment: I appreciate the response, but this isnt really helping me...

Comment: @Daft The current posted code in not enough, please provide an online demo on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It likely has something to do with the cell styling that you have in your table.. by default, cells will inherit the style of the table itself. Try adding:

```
.myTable tr, .myTable tr td{
    border: none;
}
```

This should solve your problem but I would need to see your html file in order to make sure.. I hope it helps.

Comment: That was it, much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

```
table{
    width:97%;
    max-height: 190px;
    max-height: 190px;
    padding:10px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #D3D7DC;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```